# Docker_Host on Jenkins with mvn fabric8:build

Tags: maven, docker, jenkins, fabric8

I am trying to setup Jenkins build for my simple java microservice with Kubernetes cluster.

`mvn clean package fabric8:build`

I've defined DOCKER_HOST environment variable within Jenkins
`DOCKER_HOST=tcp://192.168.20.1:2375`

My build fails with the following error after successfully building the fat JAR

`[ERROR] Failed to execute goal io.fabric8:fabric8-maven-plugin:3.5.31:build (default-cli) on project echo: Cannot create docker access object: Cannot extract API version from server http://192.168.20.1:2375 : No route to host -> [Help 1]`

My Docker host runs on linux. I changed the daemon.json to add the following and restarted docker host

`{
  "ipv6": false ,
  "live-restore": true,

  "hosts" : ["tcp://192.168.20.1:2375"]
}`

Still the issue persists:

Couple of questions:

1. Why is fabric8 resolving tcp to http? Pls looks at the error message.
2. What else needs to be done on Docker host to serve requests on tcp://192.168.20.1:2375?

TIA

Comment: 2376 is secured port. have you set DOCKER_CERT_PATH, DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY?

Comment: i am actually using 2375. Edited the post to correct the typo

Comment: can you share output of $ docker info

Comment: SOLVED: For anyone facing similar issue: Please check if there is any firewall running on the Docker host that's blocking external requests.

Comment: If you solved your issue, can you post the answer with details how to solve so other people can use it?

Answer (score 0):

This is purely a Docker host setup issue. 
To access Docker daemon remotely, tcp socket should be enabled. More details here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#examples

Based on our setup, I had edited the /etc/docker/daemon.json to add the "hosts" parameter

`{
  "ipv6": false ,
  "live-restore": true,
  "hosts" : ["tcp://192.168.20.1:2375"]
}`

Restart docker daemon using the command
`systemctl restart docker.service`

Make sure docker daemon is listening to port 2375
`netstat -tunlp | grep 2375
tcp        0      0 192.168.20.1:2375      0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      14648/dockerd`

If after doing the above if you are still not able to access Docker daemon remotely, check if there are any firewalls that are blocking the external requests.

You can either stop them or set up a rule to allow the traffic based on your configuration.

Hope this helps